# Which key is the up arrow shortcut in Visual Studio code for OSX?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm going through the interactive guide and I can following this instruction:

[image]

because

[image]

corresponds to the up arrow.

But this instruction:

[image]

seems to refer to a slightly different key (note that the up arrow is not filled in) and is not working for me.

What key does:

[image]

refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the sign for the `Shift` key (either left or right) on all Mac systems.